# How to change the default location for saving ssh on git?

Tags: git, ssh

I've been spending hours looking for a solution on this problem.
As you can see on the first image, I was trying to create ssh key:

[image]

The default directory was: `C:\Users\BC1\.ssh`
But when I look at it, I don't find the key:

[image]

The keys are located in `C:\Windows\System32`, but not in the directory shown above.

I believe that if I got this successfully, I can just edit the key and replace the content with the generated key from PuTTY and then my problem on `Permission denied` can be solved.
Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the key, just hit enter when your asked for the file name to save the key in instead of entering "key", like you did in the screenshot.

It's possible, that you can find the key in C:\Windows\system32\key right now, because this was the working directory when you first created the key.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but my belief was wrong, I can't still connect to beanstalk, and I got new error `You don't have read permissions for repository [name.git] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. Do you have any idea for this? If none, its okay.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have read permissions on "name.git"? And do you have good reason, that you're using beanstalk?  https://bitbucket.org/ is for free, even if you want private repositories.